# Rails 4 Asset Pipeline and referencing images in SCSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm checking out Rails 4 beta and when I deploy using Capistrano (Nginx, Unicorn, Postgres) it deploys the assetss successful with the manifest.

eg. `logo-515b878aa9fea59fa353f24f11c3ab.png` but I have noticed it doesn't also upload the original file `logo.png` (without the manifest).

I wanted to know if this is normal behaviour or is there something I'm missing.

And how do I call thie 'logo.png' file in the CSS file since the following doesn't work because it's not using the manifested file.

```
// Pages.SCSS file
.logo {
 background: url("logo.png") no-repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}
```

or

```
// Pages.SCSS file
.logo {
 background: url(image_path("logo.png")) no-repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: It looks like you have some sort of cache busting going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issues related to not using image_path or image_url (stopped using explicit calls to the image file within the css file). It solved my problem after a restart of the unicorn process (I thought my Capistrano recipe would of restarted the server after a cold deploy).

Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Its a kind of rails bug, found the answer [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9879)

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```